# Get Currency Conversion Value from Another table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables like below:

| Currency | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Euro | 2021-02-17 | 2000 |
| US Dollar | 2022-12-28 | 30 |
| Argentina | 2022-02-15 | 137 |

Another Table

| Currency | CUR |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | ARS |
| US Dollar | USD |

The Conversion Table

| Currency Year | CUR | YTDJAN | YTDFeb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | ARS | 116 | 118 |
| 2022 | USD | 78 | 79 |
| 2021 | ARS | 110 | 111 |

I want to have currency conversion based on date, such as for Feb 2022 date the conversion rate is YTDJan. similarly, if it is Jan, 2020 then it should Dec 2019 value.

The final table as

| Currency | Date | Amount | CUR | Converted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Euro | 2021-02-17 | 2000 | EUR | 2000 |
| US Dollar | 2022-12-28 | 30 | USD | 2370 |
| Argentina | 2022-02-15 | 137 | ARS | 15892 |

If anyone could help me with how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have separate columns for *each* month? I suggest normalising that design if I am honest, and having a separate *row* for each month. Though what are you converting these values to; there is nothing in your conversion table to denote what `116` represents for `ARS`. is that 1 USD is 116 ARS? 1 EUR is 116 ARS? 116 Euros is 1 ARS? Something *else* is `116` ARS?

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding, Yes the columns are aggregated value of conversion rate for each month. SO lets say aggregate of Jan 01 to Jan 25 is the Conversion rate for Feb invoice and so like all the months. And conversion is on EUR, meaning value in other currency have to be converted to EUR.

Comment: This is going to be much harder with separate columns. Otherwise you could just do `JOIN Conversion c ON c.CUR = t.Currency AND t.Date >= c.MonthStart AND t.Date < DATEADD(month, 1, c.MonthStart)`

Comment: So what about if you want to convert from USD to ARS? You don't convert ARS to EUR to USD, do you..? I really don't follow understand the problem here, and things are unclear. Why, for example, do you use the *month prior's* rate, and not the current month? And again, why do you have a separate column for each month when you should have a normalised approach. You would need to use `CASE` expressions with *12* clauses to be able to use your design; that will make things so unwieldy very quickly.

Comment: Hey, so no the conversion is only required from all other currency to EUR, and one month prior because the conversion rate is being calculated using average month value, so lets say for 15th Feb value, I used YTDFeb, but this YTDFeb value will change after25th. SO tha'ts why a month prior.